# Confirmation dialog for Blazor with dialog result

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, callback, blazor

I'm trying to create universal prompt dlg in Blazor similar to what we have in JS. This is the behavior I'm after:

//we prompt
bool result = await JS.InvokeAsync("confirm", $"Are you sure?");

//we wait for the result until the user click yes or no.

if(result)
{
do
}

I created the dialog but it never awaits the user's input. Here is the dialog component with Bootstrap pattern:

```
@using System.Threading

<div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header blue-dlg">
                <p class="modal-title">@Title</p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"  @onclick="() => CloseModal()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body dlg-validation">
                <p>@Message</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                @{
                    if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal()">Close</button>
                    }
                    else if (DT == DialogTypes.Prompt)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => OnConfirm(true)">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => OnConfirm(false)">No</button>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop fade @ModalClass" style="display: @ModalDisplay"></div>


@code {

    public enum DialogTypes 
    {
        Alert = 0,
        Prompt
    }

    private DialogTypes DT = DialogTypes.Alert;
    private bool confirmed = false;
    public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
    public string ModalClass = "";
    public bool ShowBackdrop = false;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }



    public async Task<bool> PromptAsync(string message, string title)
    {
        DT = DialogTypes.Prompt;
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        await Task.Delay(100);
        ModalClass = "show";
        StateHasChanged();

        return confirmed;
    }

    public async Task AlertAsync(string message, string title)
    {
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        await Task.Delay(100);
        ModalClass = "show";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public async Task CloseModal()
    {
        ModalClass = "";
        await Task.Delay(250);
        ModalDisplay = "none;";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task OnConfirm(bool confirm)
    {
        confirmed = confirm;

        await CloseModal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a manually controlled running task that you hand back to the caller.  They can then await the task and only complete themselves when you close the dialog and set the task to completed.

To do that you use the services of the `TaskCompletionSource` class.

Here's how to do it in your dialog.

```
@using System.Threading

<div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header blue-dlg">
                <p class="modal-title">@Title</p>
                @{
                    if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal()">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    }
                    else if (DT == DialogTypes.Prompt)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal(false)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body dlg-validation">
                <p>@Message</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                @{
                    if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal()">Close</button>
                    }
                    else if (DT == DialogTypes.Prompt)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal(true)">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal(false)">No</button>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop fade @ModalClass" style="display: @ModalDisplay"></div>


@code {

    public enum DialogTypes
    {
        Alert = 0,
        Prompt
    }

    private DialogTypes DT = DialogTypes.Alert;
    private bool confirmed = false;
    public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
    public string ModalClass = "";
    public bool ShowBackdrop = false;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _alertTaskCompletionSource = new();
    private Task<bool> _alertTask = Task.FromResult(true);

    private TaskCompletionSource _taskCompletionSource = new();
    private Task _task = Task.CompletedTask;

    public Task<bool> PromptAsync(string message, string title)
    {
        // Check if the modal is already running and exit if it is
        if (!_alertTask.IsCompleted || !_task.IsCompleted)
            return Task.FromResult(false);

        DT = DialogTypes.Prompt;
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "show";
        StateHasChanged();

        _alertTaskCompletionSource = new();
        _alertTask = _alertTaskCompletionSource.Task;

        return _alertTask;
    }

    public Task AlertAsync(string message, string title)
    {
        // Check if the modal is already running and exit if it is
        if (!_alertTask.IsCompleted || !_task.IsCompleted)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "show";
        StateHasChanged();

        _taskCompletionSource = new();
        _task = _taskCompletionSource.Task;

        return _alertTask;
    }

    public void CloseModal()
    {
        ModalClass = "";
        ModalDisplay = "none;";
        StateHasChanged();
        if (!_task.IsCompleted)
            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult();

    }

    public void CloseModal(bool result)
    {
        ModalClass = "";
        ModalDisplay = "none;";
        StateHasChanged();
        _alertTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
    }

}
```

And here's a test page to demo it working:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.OpenModal>Open Dialog</button>
</div>

<MyModal @ref=_modal />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Result = @_result</pre>

</div>

@code {
    private MyModal? _modal;
    private bool _result;

    private async Task OpenModal()
    {
        if (_modal is not null)
        {
            _result = await _modal.PromptAsync("Do You Really Want To", "Exit Check");
            // Do whatever you want with the result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tested and works. I just cleaned my markup from the example and a small bug with the message, so we have a complete component with your solution:

Answer (score 0):

Here is MrC aka Shaun Curtis solution without my bad markup to a complete component:
Fixed markup:

```
<div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header blue-dlg">
            <p class="modal-title">@Title</p>
            @{
                if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
                {
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="() => CloseModal()">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                }
                else if (DT == DialogTypes.Prompt)
                {
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="() => CloseModal(false)">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                                            &times;
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                }
            }
        </div>
        @{
            if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
            {
                <div class="modal-body dlg-validation">
                    <p>@Message</p>
                </div>
            }
        }
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            @{
                if (DT == DialogTypes.Alert)
                {
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal()">Close</button>
                }
                else if (DT == DialogTypes.Prompt)
                {
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal(true)">Yes</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => CloseModal(false)">No</button>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and fixed alert:

```
    public Task<bool> PromptAsync(string title)
{
    // Check if the modal is already running and exit if it is
    if (!_alertTask.IsCompleted || !_task.IsCompleted)
        return Task.FromResult(false);

    DT = DialogTypes.Prompt;
    Title = title;
    ModalDisplay = "block;";
    ModalClass = "show";
    StateHasChanged();

    _alertTaskCompletionSource = new();
    _alertTask = _alertTaskCompletionSource.Task;

    return _alertTask;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to modify my answer with your corrections.  It means there's one accepted answer.